# What does this syntax mean in Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I don't understand the syntax of this code. Is it an array or a function call?

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
```

The same in Java:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Comment: What do you want? explain...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to be a generic type. Rather than returning the Parent class, it tries to cast it first as what you are trying to get. Ex:

```
public static <T> T getById() { 
    return (T) this.userService.getById(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
```

or

```
val editText: EditText = findViewById(R.id.editText)
```

mean the same

In the above kotlin code:

edittext-your variable
findViewById(R.id.editText)-is just finding the id of edittext

```
<EditText>
```

or :EditText -is a typecast which simply tells the variable that the return type will be of type ediText

Invoking findViewById() can be slow, especially in case of huge view hierarchies, so Android Extensions tries to minimize findViewById() calls by caching views in containers.Now in kotlin you can omit using findviewbyid anymore and you can  just simply write the above as:

```
val editText=editText
```

where,
val editText - variable
=editText(on the right side) - id you want to find

Hope this answers your question.